# Cannot use import statement outside a module -- angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to suscribe an observable in my app component inside the javascript function that it returns an observable, but i am having the next error when i am trying to load the page before the app component.

I need to do it, because my application has one part is mobile and other is web, as consequence the user sometimes clicks on the button back pressed in the app

When the user clicks on the back pressed, i call the javascript

```
class WebViewActivity : BaseActivity() {
  
    lateinit var webView : WebView
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NotView)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)
        webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
        loadPage()
    }

    private fun loadPage() {
        webView.clearCache(true)
        webView.webViewClient = ActivityWebView(this)
        webView.webChromeClient = ActivityWebViewChrome(this)
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(BridgeJavaScript(this, webView), "Test")
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:9000/test")
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        webView.url?.let {
         this.webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:bacKPressed()",null);
        }
    }
}
```

The when the user click on the backpressed, i call the javascript function, as result i need that the typescript is  listening  all time  the event when it have been called.

> this.webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:bacKPressed()",null);

[image: backpressed]

The Angular version is 8

The assets function is the next .js

```
import {of} from "rxjs";


function bacKPressed() {
   return of(true)
}
```

The angular.json is the next

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/functions.js"
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app"
}
```

if i remove the observable in javascript function, it is ok, also the page loaded.

```
function bacKPressed() {
   return  true
}
```

The typescript code is the next

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
declare function bacKPressed(): Observable<boolean>;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

/**
 * Clase inicial de la aplicación
 *
 * *Initial app class*
 *
 */
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    bacKPressed().subscribe(()=> {
      console.log('The onBackPressed was called');
    });
  }
}
```

The error is the next

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> main.0dd98e5cd968fc0f00c4.js:2 Fatal. External context not found.
> Application unavailable.

If i change the import to required, it shows the next

```
const {of} = require("rxjs");

function bacKPressed() {
   return of(true)
}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> at scripts.13f7030c5c675b4edf74.js:1

Comment: It’s unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish here. What I’m seeing is not ‘standard’ angular stuff..?

Comment: @MikeOne . I am trying to create an function javascript that it returns an observable and suscribe it, but the page is not loaded. If i removed the of, it loads

Comment: Yes I understand.. but that doesn’t really make sense in real world angular apps. You want a utility function? Normally something like this would live inside an angular service. If you want a simple utility, that is also possible. It has to be a TS file and you would actually have to export your function from that. Than you can simply import it and you wouldn’t need the declare. So the question stays - why do you want to ‘create a function javascript’..?

Comment: @mikeOne because my app has one part is mobile and other parts is web, then i neeed to send an event from the mobile to webpage, because the users sometimes clicks on the backpressed in the mobile. I am going to update the  code

Comment: Alright. I’d love to help you out here, but you need to describe your scenarios a bit better so I understand what you need.

Comment: @mikeOne i updated the post

Comment: That’s more clear. I don’t think this approach (with a function call) is realistic. I would look at triggering an actual even on window or document (dispatchEvent) and have your angular app listen to that event (addEventListener)

Comment: do you have any code aboyt it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @MikeOne i am going to check it , thank you